# How does one Transform AppSettings in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1, appsettings

I was led to believe that `appsettings.json` and its environment counterparts (dev, staging, production) replaced Web.config transforms.

This works fine in a dev environment, where variables for those environments exist in the `launchSettings.json`

However, if I use the Publish feature, configuring the Publish to use the Staging build configuration which I created, no transform appears.

I've read elsewhere that you need to create Environment variables. Really! Is that what it has come to? We now have an armada of System Environment variables for Applications which may or may not (over time) be running on the IIS (or other) Web server on that box.

At the moment I am manually copying and pasting a "staging" `appsettings.json` after doing a publish. I already have to copy and paste a pre-prepared Web.config file into that folder as it is no longer available to configure in the IDE (yet curiously, still gets produced during a Publish operation).

Is there another way to have maintainable transforms for deployments which is something akin to the transforms of the config files of old?

Comment: You don't - you no longer *need* to. It's a *lot* easier to use different settings now. You can load configuration from multiple sources. Adding a new one *overrides* older settings. Instead of transforming `web.config` for staging or production you can load `appsettings.json` first and `appsettings.staging.json` second to override settings for production. That `staging` value can easily come from an environment variable *or* the command line, *or* you can simply *not* include the extra setting file.

Comment: "Multiple sources" means command line, database or environment variables. Ini files, yaml, anything you can write that can read configuration and emit it as a key/value pair of strings. You can use a *database* configuration source to override settings on top of `appsettings.json`, `appsettings.{environment}.json` etc

Comment: This is described in the documentation itself - [Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.1). This is *far* clearer than any SO question or random forum discussion and shows that you *don't* need to create any environment variables. Using a well-known environment variable as a source is only *one* way you can detect the environment. You can pick any method you want. The only thing that matters is the order you register the providers.

Comment: Finally, this works for any .NET Core application, not just ASP.NT Core. Check [Essential .NET: Configuration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt632279.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) which explains how the same things work for Console applications. WebHostBuilder simply provides some sensible initial registrations.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks. I'll add some logging to see if I can obtain the behavior I want.

Comment: As for the downvotes, the third paragraphs doesn't help at all. It's PRECISELY because .NET Core runs outside IIS that env variables are used. Environment variables are one of the most useful configuration mechanisms for containers for example. As for the rest - configuration is already well explained in the docs, all third-party tutorials, hundreds of blog posts and multiple *duplicate* SO questions. Yes, it's a surprise when coming from ASP.NET to find that things have changed so much

Comment: Don't add logging. Read the docs. You *can* get the behaviour you want and a lot more. You don't *need* transforms, they were simply one way to achieve different configs per environment. There are far better ways now. You have to understand how the new infrastructure works instead of trying to make it work like the old one.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I understand that it is all different and is meant to be agnostic of web server, but why does the Publish operation still produce a Web.config file (an IIS-centric artifact)?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I think the OP's comments regarding Environmental Variables is a fair enough point of view. Sure, the Docker acolytes can leverage them. But you could really end up with a cluttered mess of System Environmental variables over time as apps appear and disappear from the system. Seems like a maintenance burden to me. The Web.config way of setting them is my preference. But again, you have to do that outside the IDE. From a maintenance perspective, I think that is a step back. But I'm not a dev ops guy and they are probably used to that.

Comment: @DavidRogersDev in this case I'd suggest you misunderstand how environment variables are used too. Check Chris Pratt's answers, read the links to the documentations to understand how things work *now*. It's not a step back at all. It's different.

Comment: Downvotes leave a sour taste in my mouth. Unless that gets reversed, this question gets deleted. This is the one thing I hate about SO. It wasn't a bad question.

Comment: @onefootswill It's not a bad question at all. The fact that a little frustration crept through does not make it a bad question. I've given SO feedback about this kind of thing, but they have a proven track record of not listening to their users. This is why I generally prefer the MSDN forums.

Answer (score 5):

This actually confuses a lot of people as the configurations in Visual Studio don't really do anything for an ASP.NET Core app. ASP.NET Core apps are intended to be compiled once for any environment. The actual "environment" it runs in is determined via config, namely the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable. In other words, whether you deploy as Debug/Staging/Release/Whatever in Visual Studio, it's the same app code. (The only time this is not the case is if you were to employ compiler directives in your code, like `#if DEBUG ... #endif`, for example. That's not very common and honestly not recommended anyways.)

I think you misunderstood about environment variables. You can still use JSON config and such in production. The only environment variable that needs to be set is the aforementioned `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT`.

Long and short, if you set `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` to "Production", then your `appsettings.Production.json` will be loaded as you'd expect. There's no transformaton that occurs. Instead, the environment-specific config serves to extend and override other config.

Answer (score 5):

I find this quite annoying too. I liked being able to change my solution configuration and test (locally) with production or staging config values.

Anyway, here is a low-ish friction option. There may be better out there.

1. Put all your production settings in `appsettings.json`. Worst case scenario is that something uses all the security levels of your production service, which is better than giving development access by accident. And it means you don't need an environment variable on your production boxes, so there's also nothing to accidentally delete
2. Create a `appsettings.Development.json` with your dev database connection string, etc. You only need the items that are different, and you don't have to transform them, they'll overwrite any matches in appsettings.json
3. `lauchsettings.json` should already be setup with a `profiles` > `{name}` > `environmentVariables` > `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` with a value of `Development`. You can use this as your live test toggle. Comment out that line and you will use the Production settings.

If you want to add a Staging level, add yourself a new profile and `appsettings.staging.json` file. You will need to add the environment variable, but this is usually less of an issue and less of a risk than doing it on Production. I haven't thought of an easy way to use Staging and Development on the same box though