# Transform appsettings in Azure Pipeline

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops

how can i configure the azure pipeline to use different appsettings files according to the environment?

I have 4 different files and I can't transform appsettings.json according to the environment.

[image: my appsettings files]

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: You could use a powershell task at the beginning to set the environment like `$Env:ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = "Development\Homolog"`. Or you could change the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` under appsettings.json file. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52753893/how-does-one-transform-appsettings-in-asp-net-core) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43073959/how-do-i-transform-appsettings-json-in-a-net-core-mvc-project).